# Observable Collection Property Changed on Item in the Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, collections, observablecollection

I have an `ObservableCollection<T>`. I've bound it to a ListBox control and I've added `SortDescriptions` to the Items collection on the ListBox to make the list sort how I want.

I want to resort the list at **ANY** point when any property changed on a child element.

All my child elements implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: So, you're binding your OC to a Listbox and have the sortdescription on the listbox?

Comment: That is correct. When a property of a child item is changed, I would like the sort to reflect this change.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Brute force:

1. Attach handler to each PropertyChanged event for each child item
2. Grab the ListCollectionView from your CollectionViewSource
3. Call Refresh.

**EDIT:**

The code for 1, 2 would live in your code-behind.

For #1, you'd do something like:

```
private void Source_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Action)
    {
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
            foreach( SomeItem item in e.NewItems)
            {
               item.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(_SomeItem_PropertyChanged); 
            }
            break;
....
**HANDLE OTHER CASES HERE**
....
      }
}
```

For #2, in your CollectionChanged handler, you would do something like:

```
private void _SomeItem_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListCollectionView lcv = (ListCollectionView)(CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(theListBox.ItemsSource));
    lcv.Refresh();
}
```

EDIT2:
However, in this case, I would **strongly** suggest that you also check ListCollectionView.NeedsRefresh and only refresh if that is set.  There's no reason to re-sort if your properties have changed which don't affect the sort.

Comment: Would this code live in my presentation tier? Window.Xaml.Cs?

What would code for #1 and #2 look like?

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. I ended up only using the second part, since in my case I have an event that is causing the change, so I only needed #2.

Answer (score 0):

This works. Whenever the collection changes, it re-sorts the collection. Might be doable in a more efficient way but this is the gist of it.

```
public partial class TestWindow : Window {
        ObservableCollection<TestClass> oc;
        public TestWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
            // Fill in the OC for testing 
            oc = new ObservableCollection<TestClass>();
            foreach( char c in "abcdefghieeddjko" ) {
                oc.Add( new TestClass( c.ToString(), c.ToString(), c.GetHashCode() ) );
            }

            lstbox.ItemsSource = oc;
            // Set up the sorting (this is how you did it.. doesn't work)
            lstbox.Items.SortDescriptions.Add( new SortDescription("A", ListSortDirection.Ascending) );
            // This is how we're going to do it
            oc.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler( oc_Sort );
        }

        void oc_Sort( object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e ) {
            // This sorts the oc and returns IEnumerable
            var items = oc.OrderBy<TestClass, int>( ( x ) => ( x.C ) );
            // Rest converst IEnumerable back to OC and assigns it
            ObservableCollection<TestClass> temp = new ObservableCollection<TestClass>();
            foreach( var item in items ) {
                temp.Add( item );
            }
            oc = temp;
        }

        private void Button_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e ) {
            string a = "grrrr";
            string b = "ddddd";
            int c = 383857;
            oc.Add( new TestClass( a, b, c ) );
        }


    }

    public class TestClass : INotifyPropertyChanged {
        private string a;
        private string b;
        private int c;

        public TestClass( string f, string g, int i ) {
            a = f;
            b = g;
            c = i;
        }
        public string A {
            get { return a; }
            set { a = value; OnPropertyChanged( "A" ); }
        }
        public string B {
            get { return b; }
            set { b = value; OnPropertyChanged( "B" ); }
        }
        public int C {
            get { return c; }
            set { c = value; OnPropertyChanged( "C" ); }
        }

        #region onpropertychanged

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged( string propertyName ) {
            if( this.PropertyChanged != null ) {
                PropertyChanged( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( propertyName ) );
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ServiceManager.TestWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="TestWindow" Height="500" Width="500">
    <DockPanel>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" x:Name="lstbox">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Content="{Binding Path=A}"/>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Path=B}"/>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Path=C}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Click" />
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: ObservableCollection<T> does not listen to the PropertyChanged events on its elements, so this will fail to re-sort when a property of one of the elements is changed. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd252944.aspx